# How can I get /etc/issue to display for longer?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell

Before the login screen shows I can see the lines written on /etc/issue but it only appears for a few seconds, how could I get it to display for longer or wait for an input?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/bash_bashrc` and `/etc/.bash_profile` for any commands that might be clearing the screen, or outputting an ANSI code to clear screen, or otherwise resetting the terminal.

Comment: Went to check /etc/bash.bashrc and I couldn't find the /etc/.bash_profile but in bash.bashrc I didn't see any command that might clear the screen or reset the terminal. (Might be misreading something inthe file but I'm not sure)

Comment: try renaming those files and see if issue persists.  If so, it might be an ANSI escape code embedded somewhere.  Also it might be some funky systemd login option as well.